# How to recreate lost html options

Tags: html, django, google-app-engine

Hi I upgrded from django 0.96 to 1.2 and know no other difference between "before" and "after" html options won't display anymore. I know this info is coming a little short, but maybe you can know what happened?
Before:
[image]

After

[image]

Some code that seems exactly the same except that djagno dsipatcher was upgraded, is:

```
<div id="searchmain">{% include "form.html" %}</div>
```

And form.html

```
{% load i18n %}
<form action="/li" id="cse-search-box"><div><input value='{{q}}' type="text" id="searchtext" name="q" size="31" />
<input type="hidden" value='{{t}}' name="t" />  
{% include "../market/categories.html" %}
{% ifequal logo "montao" %}
<select name="l" id="search_area" class="search_area"><option value=''>{% trans "Entire" %}</option> 
<!--
<option id='heading2'>{% trans "name" %}</option> -->
            <option id='heading2'>São Paulo</option>             
                        <option id='heading2'>Rio de Janeiro</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Espírito Santo</option> 
                      <option id='heading2'>Minas Gerais</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Paraná</option>  
                          <option id='heading2'>Santa Catarina</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Rio Grande do Sul</option>                        
                        <option id='heading2'>Bahia</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Pernambuco</option>                        
                        <option id='heading2'>Ceará</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
                      <option id='heading2'>Amazonas</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Distrito Federal</option> 
                   <option id='heading2'>Pará</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Maranhão</option> 
                           <option id='heading2'>Goiás</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Paraíba</option> 
                       <option id='heading2'>Alagoas</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Piauí</option>                    
                        <option id='heading2'>Mato Grosso</option> 
                         <option id='heading2'>Mato Grosso do Sul</option>  
                        <option id='heading2'>Sergipe</option> 
                          <option id='heading2'>Rondônia</option> 
                          <option id='heading2'>Tocantins</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Acre</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Amapá</option> 
                        <option id='heading2'>Roraima</option> 
</select> {% endifequal %} 
<!-- 
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" size="35" maxlength="50" value="{{plat}}" />
<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" size="35" maxlength="50" value="{{plon}}" />
-->
<input type="submit" id="searchbutton" value="{% trans "Go" %}" />
</div></form>
```

Updated to this and still same problem:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form action="/li" id="cse-search-box"><div><input value='{{q}}' type="text" id="searchtext" name="q" size="31" />
<input type="hidden" value='{{t}}' name="t" />  
{% include "../market/categories.html" %}
{% ifequal logo "montao" %}
<select name="l" id="search_area" class="search_area"><option value=''>{% trans "Entire" %}</option> 
<!--
<option >{% trans "name" %}</option> -->
             <option >São Paulo</option>             
                         <option >Rio de Janeiro</option> 
                         <option >Espírito Santo</option> 
                       <option >Minas Gerais</option> 
                         <option >Paraná</option>  
                           <option >Santa Catarina</option> 
                         <option >Rio Grande do Sul</option>                        
                         <option >Bahia</option> 
                         <option >Pernambuco</option>                        
                         <option >Ceará</option> 
                         <option >Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
                       <option >Amazonas</option> 
                         <option >Distrito Federal</option> 
                    <option >Pará</option> 
                         <option >Maranhão</option> 
                            <option >Goiás</option> 
                         <option >Paraíba</option> 
                        <option >Alagoas</option> 
                         <option >Piauí</option>                    
                         <option >Mato Grosso</option> 
                          <option >Mato Grosso do Sul</option>  
                         <option >Sergipe</option> 
                           <option >Rondônia</option> 
                           <option >Tocantins</option> 
                         <option >Acre</option> 
                         <option >Amapá</option> 
                         <option >Roraima</option> 
</select> {% endifequal %} 
<!-- 
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" size="35" maxlength="50" value="{{plat}}" />
<input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" size="35" maxlength="50" value="{{plon}}" />
-->
<input type="submit" id="searchbutton" value="{% trans "Go" %}" />
</div></form>
```

I'll try whatever you can propose! Thanks. BTW Here is the expected output that I could paste in with no dynamics:

```
<div id="searchmain"> <form action="/li" id="cse-search-box"><div><input value='' type="text" id="searchtext" name="q" size="31" /> <input type="hidden" value='' name="t" /> <select name="cg" id="cat" class="search_category"> <option value='' >All</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat1' >-- VEHICLES --</option> <option value='2'   id='cat2' >Cars</option> <option value='3'    id='cat3' >Motorcycles</option> <option value='4'    id='cat4' >Accessories &amp; Parts</option> <!--<option value='5'    id='cat5' >Other vehicles</option>--> <option value=''    style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat6' >-- PROPERTIES --</option> <option value='7'    id='cat7' >Apartments</option> <option value='8'    id='cat8' >Houses</option> <option value='9'    id='cat9' >Commercial properties</option> <option value='10'   id='cat10' >Land</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat11' >-- ELECTRONICS --</option> <option value='12'    id='cat12' >Mobile phones &amp; Gadgets</option> <option value='13'   id='cat13' >TV/Audio/Video/Cameras</option> <option value='14'   id='cat14' >Computers</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat15' >-- HOME &amp; PERSONAL ITEMS --</option> <option value='16'  id='cat16' >Home &amp; Garden</option> <option value='17'    id='cat17' >Clothes/Watches/Accessories</option> <option value='18'   id='cat18' >For Children</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat19' >-- LEISURE/SPORTS/HOBBIES --</option> <option value='20'    id='cat20' >Sports &amp; Outdoors</option> <option value='21'     id='cat21' >Hobby &amp; Collectables</option> <option value='22'   id='cat22' >Music/Movies/Books</option> <option value='23'   id='cat23' >Pets</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3'     id='cat24' >-- BUSINESS TO BUSINESS --</option> <option value='25'    id='cat25' >Professional/Office equipment</option> <option value='26'    id='cat26' >Business for sale</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat27' >-- JOBS &amp; SERVICES --</option> <option value='28'   id='cat28' >Jobs</option> <option value='29'    id='cat29' >Services</option> <option value='30'    id='cat30' >Events &amp; Catering</option> <option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' >--</option> <option value='31'    id='cat31' >Others</option> </select> <!-- 
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" size="35" maxlength="50" value="" /> <input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" size="35" maxlength="50" value="" />
--> <input type="submit" id="searchbutton" value="Go" /> </div></form> </div>
```

Comment: why are you coding your <select> in the template? That should be handled by the form class.

Comment: What @Mark said. Also, have you tried running the output through an HTML validator?

Comment: I understand that should be handled by the form class. I didn't have a form class since not being able to make the form class translate stuff like categories that should be multilingual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's realted to your issue, but you can't have 2 elements with the same `id` attribute. `id` has to be unique! If you need to give 2 elements the same style, that's what `class` attribute is made for.

And yeah, it's possible that it's causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom. I'll follow the advice and report back. Can you point more exactly where in my code this problem is? Is it the heading2 id?

Comment: if that's indeed the problem, I strongly suggest you pick up dom monster (http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/), it detects those issues and many more.